# Custom Newsletter template

Tags: emails

I'm trying to create an email newsletter template to make it easier to send out blog newsletters by looping over entries and generating the email straight out of craft. I did this often with Wordpress.

However I'm getting twig syntax errors because of the inline CSS. I know you can do this `<style>{{ source('file.css') }}</style>` but that's not going to cut it for all the tables I need to add inline CSS to.

Am I missing a Twig filter that I could wrap all my HTML code it?

Just to be clear I am only trying to generate, not send the email newsletter through Craft.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can include standard HTML in Twig templates. So something like this would work:

```
<table style="background-color: gray">
```

You don't **have** to use Twig filters to add CSS or CSS files. Although you could create some CSS variables using `{% set gray = '#eee' %}` or `{% set border = 'border: 1px solid black' %}` for repeated styles such as colors, borders, etc., and then reference those like this, using the variable name:

```
<table style="background-color: {{ gray }}; {{ border }}>
```